# Date change in JVM

Tags: java, date, jvm

I am currently working on app that consists of second app's code (let's name it "App B") that I cannot change (it's a compiled java code in *.adb file exported from [Blaze Advisor](https://www.fico.com/en/products/fico-blaze-advisor-decision-rules-management-system)). My code looks something like that:

```
public class RunSecondApp {

public Response runAppB(ApplicationBAdapter applicationBAdapter){    
    return applicationBAdapter.run(request);
}
```

Inside App B there are many invocations to current date (in Blaze Advisor it's CurrentLocalDate method - I think it's compiling to Java's LocalDate method but I'm not sure). Now what I need is to somehow mock the current date so that this invocations to current date in App B would return not today's date but a substitute.

Changing the system date is not an option.

I've read about PowerMock, JMockito, Expectations.class but every time I try this it's failing. Did anyone try something similar to this?

Comment: Would it perhaps be possible to run the tests inside a container / VM whose date you could modify to your preference?

Comment: Blaze is a business program based on srl language - we can export project to *adb file that is somehow translated to java language but it's impossible to modify it.

Comment: Yes, FICO Blaze Advisor Decision Rules Management System

Comment: Modifying the time of the device is not enough?

Comment: In my app I call App B multiple times (Spring Batch) everytime with different substitude date. Changing date on device one time would be too risky. I don't want to think about consequences of that solution while some user would run app and it would change his device's date multiple times or what would happen if the app would crasch in the middle. I don't think it would be a good solution.